# How can I make the circumference of the circle black when clicked in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, geometry, swiftui

When the image is clicked, I want to make the surrounding area black. How can I do that at SwiftUI?

[image]

Comment: How did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `.overlay` and `.stroke` modifiers

Check the code below, Hope it will help you.

```
struct CircleOutLineView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                CircleView(fillColor: .blue, outlineColor: .black)
                CircleView(fillColor: .red, outlineColor: .black)
                CircleView(fillColor: .yellow, outlineColor: .black)
                CircleView(fillColor: .green, outlineColor: .black)
                CircleView(fillColor: .purple, outlineColor: .black)
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(height: 100)
        }
    }
}

struct CircleOutLineView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CircleOutLineView()
    }
}

struct CircleView: View {
    
    @State private var isTapped = false
    
    var fillColor: Color
    var outlineColor: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(fillColor)
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
            .overlay(Circle().stroke(outlineColor, lineWidth: isTapped ? 1 : 0))
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isTapped.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: overlay method solved my problem, thank you.